# How can I restitue a raw audio data stream using WebAudio?

Tags: signal-processing, web-audio-api

I use WebAudio API and basically my setup is fairly simple.

I use 1 AudioWorkletNode as an emitter and another one as a receiver

emitter:

```
  process(inputs, outputs) {

    inputs[ 0 ].length && this.port.postMessage( inputs[ 0 ] );

    return ( true );

  }
```

receiver:

```
  inputs = [ new Float32Array(128), new Float32Array(128) ]

  constructor() {
    super();

    // Create a message port to receive messages from the main thread
    this.port.onmessage = (event) => {

      this.inputs = event.data.inputs;

    };

  }

  process( inputs, outputs) {

    const output = outputs[0];

    for (let channel = 0; channel < output.length; ++channel) {

      output[ channel ].set( this.inputs[ channel ] );

    }

    return true;
  }
```

on client side I have

```
//emitter
    this.inputWorklet.port.onmessage = e => this.receiverWorklet.port.postMessage( { inputs: e.data } );
```

and for receiving the data I have connected the nodes together

```
this.receiverWorklet.connect( this.gainNode );
```

This works but my problem is that the sound is really glitchy
One thing I though of is there might be a delay between events also WebAudio is in a DOM context

Do you have any ideas How I could achieve a fluid stream restitution?
or maybe another technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the glitchy audio is that your code only works if everything always happens in the exact same order.

- The input worklet's `process()` function needs to be called. It sends an event.
- The event needs to pass through the main thread.
- The event needs to arrive at the receiver worklet.
- Only after that the receiver worklet's `process()` function needs to be called.

Since there is no buffer it always has to happen in the exact same order. If for some reason the main thread is busy and it can't process the events right away the receiver will continue playing the old audio.

I think you can almost keep the current implementation by buffering a few events in your receiver worklet before you start playing. It will of course also add some latency.

Another approach would be to use a `SharedArrayBuffer` instead of sending events. Your input worklet would write to the `SharedArrayBuffer` and your receiver worklet would read from it.

Comment: thank you for your answer any simple code for the sharedbuffer technique with low latency? Thanks in advance

Comment: I've tried with a buffer of 128 * 64 and get a correct sound but a lot of latency, my aim is to send it via peer connections so I don't see how I could use sharedArraybuffer efficiently in that case. Do you have any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: There is a library called [`ringbuf.js`](https://github.com/padenot/ringbuf.js). It's documented here: https://ringbuf-js.netlify.app/. There are also a few `SharedArrayBuffer`-related examples in the [Web Audio Examples](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/web-audio-samples) from the Chrome team.

Comment: If you send the audio via a peer connection I assume you're using a `DataChannel` for that. You could transfer that `DataChannel` to a Web Worker and send your audio there via a `SharedArrayBuffer`. It won't help to reduce the network latency but it will make sure the data doesn't need to get piped through the main thread.

Comment: Thank you for your answer if you had any code to transfer data channel it would be great.I'm trying to reduce as much as possible processes on the main thread an at this point I don't know how to move a datachannel to a main thread as I only see some postMessage function.Thanks in advance

Comment: According to [web-platform-tests](https://wpt.fyi/results/webrtc-extensions/transfer-datachannel.html?label=master&label=experimental&aligned&view=subtest) it currently only works in Safari. But the tests itself show quite nicely how it's supposed to work. https://github.com/web-platform-tests/wpt/blob/e731a1368a9d3436487e0996ecfebbef5a58f485/webrtc-extensions/transfer-datachannel.html